# Why extended class does not have the relationship in Laravel with Modules?

Tags: php, laravel, module, relationship

I have a `Person` class (`App\Models\Person`) and an `Organization` class (`App\Models\Organization`) which have a polymorphic relationship with `User` (`App\Models\User`). I am using Modules (`nwidart/laravel-modules`).
In my `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` in the boot method I have this relationship:

```
        Relation::morphMap(
            [
                'organizations' => 'App\Models\Organization',
                'persons'       => 'App\Models\Person',
            ]
        );
```

Now, I have a module called `Contracts`, that module has a `Person` model (`Modules\Contracts\Entities\Person`) which extends from `App\Models\Person`. I also have a `User` model (`Modules\Contracts\Entities\User`) which extends from `App\Models\User`.
I added the following code to the `ContractsServiceProvider` boot method:

```
        Relation::morphMap(
            [
                'persons'       => 'Modules\Contracts\Entities\Person',
            ]
        );
```

Now, if I go to any controller and I load a `Person` like this:

```
$person = \App\Models\Person::find( 1 );
```

The relationship with `User` doesn't exist, so I can't do `$person->users()->first();`

But if I load a Person like this:

```
$person = \Modules\Contracts\Entities\Person::find( 1 );
```

The relationship works like a charm.

The fun part is that all the relationship methods with users are inside the files **User.php** and **Person.php**  in the `app\Models` directory.

In **app\Models\User.php** I have:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {

    public function usable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

In my **app\Models\Person.php**

```
class Person extends Model {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphMany( User::class, 'usable', 'usable_type', 'usable_id' );
    }

}
```

Also, when I create an `\App\Models\User`from an `\App\Models\Person` like this:

```
$person = \App\Models\Person::find( 1 );
$person->users()->create( [ ... ] );
```

The record in the database in the users table is like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                 email             | usable_id | usable_type       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | some@email.com                    |         3 | App\Models\Person |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if I create the user from a `\Modules\Contracts\Entities\Person` like this:

```
$person = \Modules\Contracts\Entities\Person::find( 1 );
$person->users()->create( [ ... ] );
```

The record in the database in the users table is like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                 email             | usable_id | usable_type       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | some@email.com                    |         3 | persons           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wonder if the `ContractsServiceProvider` is somehow overriding the `AppServiceProvider` and causing my relationship to fail. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is overriding it .. the morphMap is just an array, so you can't have 2 of the same key

Comment: Then, is there a solution? Which would be the proper way to fix it? I want the relationship to work in the module as well as outside the module, what if I need another module with the same relationship?

Comment: the morph map is only so that you don't need to have the fully qualified class name directly in the database and can use a mapped name instead ... you would need a unique name for every single model you want to use the map for